# how to assign table aliases through activerecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to use ActiveRecord to access a table in a different database.  the normal sql would look something like

```
select * from users, group_users@db2
where users.id = group_users.user_id
and group_users.group_id = 1
```

I've tried adding the @db2 to the table name in the class file

`self.table_name = 'group_users@db2'`

but of course that causes issues in the "where" clause as it puts

```
where users.id = group_users@db2.user_id
```

so I was looking for a way to alias the table_name attribute, that way

```
select * from users, group_users@db2 gu
where users.id = gu.user_id
and group_users.group_id = 1
```

Comment: IMO you would be best off with creating a function or a view in your db, where you do the needed magic, and then call that from Rails.

Comment: @iceman The business won't let me change the schema :-(

Comment: see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Connection+to+multiple+databases+in+different+models

Comment: @bjhaid close but not quite.  that requires me running a separate sql statement in each database, as I would have to use a different connection.  I want to be able to use the same connection (and the same query) to go cross databases

Comment: @MattWestlake how do you establish the sql connection, show the sample connection URL

Comment: @bjhaid `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter => 'oracle_enhanced',
    :driver => 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver',
    :url => 'my_db_url'
    :username =>  'xxxxx',
    :password => 'yyyyy')`

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter => 'oracle_enhanced',
    :driver => 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver',
    :url => 'my_2nd_db_url'
    :username =>  'xxxxx',
    :password => 'yyyyy')

Comment: @MattWestlake I am referring to the URL you are using with easy_connect on sqlplus

Comment: @bjhaid i'm not using sqlplus

Comment: Changing-the-schema-prohibition includes creating a synonym?

Comment: @MattWestlake whatever you are using there should be a way to establish easy_connect to the DB, you can use that URL to generate a connection and run your query, e.g: `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection("username/password@db_url/schema")` then `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('select * from users, group_users@db2')` should work

Comment: @bjhaid except at that point I loose the relation between users & group_users (EX: I cannot say users.firs.group_users.first.group_id), and that's not using activeRecord ORM that's just telling activeRecord to run sql which is what I do not want to do

Comment: @RubyRacer The table synonym was only my thought for a work around to the problem of using database links.